# Summation of series with 'for' loops

Tags: php, loops

How can I do this equation `1+2+3...+n` or `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10` in PHP? I have tried like this but the result is `136101521283645` something like this. What is wrong?

```
$sum =0;

for ($i = 1; $i<10; $i++){
  $sum = $sum + $i;
  echo $sum;
}
```

Comment: you're printing the intermediate steps, without a carriageline between each.  Your sequence is 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$sum =0;

for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55 but with your solution its showing 45

Comment: yea its working thanks, just needed to put the less than or equal in the condition I should have found this though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a recursive function and have the above sum for every number

```
function addition($var) {

    if($var > 0) return $total = $var + addition($var - 1);
}

echo addition(20); // 210

echo addition(30); // 465
```

Comment: thanks, your solution is cool but I'm just trying to  do it with for loop.